# Sybase login error, using ODBC Driver, system error 127, specified procedure could not be loaded

Tags: odbc, sybase, sap-ase

I am tring to connect to Sybase server through an application which uses ODBC Drivers to connect, but when I attempt to login it was throwing an error saying

> ERROR ESTABLISHING CONNECTION, SPECIFIED DRIVER COULD NOT BE LOADED
>   DUE TO SYSTEM ERROR 127: THE SPECIFIED PROCEDURE COULD NOT BE
>   FOUND.(SYBASE ASE ODBC DRIVER, C:\PROGRA`2\SYBASE\ODBC\SYODASE.DLL).
>   MICROSOFT OLEDB PROVIDER FOR OBDC DRIVERS.

I am using Sybase ASE 15.7 AND Sybase Open Client ODBC Driver 15.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO.  Remember that on the internet, capitalization is considered shouting, so please try not to overuse it when asking your question.  Also, I added the [Sybase-ase] tag, and [odbc] tags, since they seemed relevant to your question, and proper tagging will get your question in front of the right people faster.  You also may need to add additional information about how you registered the ODBC source, configuration parameters and your connection parameters.

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20116.1500/html/aseodbc/aseodbc42.htm

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20116.1500/html/aseodbc/CHDCGBEH.htm

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this error indicates that some dependencies could not be loaded.  Assuming your `PATH` is all the right locations on it you may be missing some files from the client.